# A book or short story with normal time and reverse time happening in the same space

Tags: story-identification, novel

The story has something to do about two times going opposite "directions" and intertwining.

People in the normal time such as ours see the effects in their own time with strangeness such as having buildings getting deconstructed instead of constructed because of reverse time.

That's all I can remember.

Comment: There are *lots* of stories on the ["time in reverse" theme](http://sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/time_in_reverse). Please try to remember more. How long ago did you read it? Is it set on Earth? Present, past, or future? Is it told in first or third person? Is the main character a man, woman, boy, girl, non-human? Do people begin life by being dug up from their graves?

Comment: Maybe more than a decade or two ago :) . It would be set on Earth. Not sure about the point of view. I don't remember anything about graves. Also, this isn't about time reversal but about two time streams "colliding" with each other in "opposite directions".

Answer (score 3):

There are many stories on the ["Time in Reverse"](http://sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/time_in_reverse) theme. Perhaps you're thinking of the 1967 novel [*Counter-Clock World*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?950) by [Philip K. Dick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_K._Dick). If so, maybe one of [these covers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?950) will ring a bell. Here are some excerpts from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-Clock_World) plot summary:

> The novel describes a future in which time has started to move in reverse, resulting in the dead reviving in their own graves ("old-birth"), living their lives in reverse, and eventually returning to the womb where they split into an egg and a sperm during copulation between a recipient woman and a man.
>
> [. . . .]
>
> The story takes place in a (then-future) fictional 1998, and centers around Anarch Peak, a black religious leader who had died in 1971 and is expected to rise soon. Sebastian Hermes, an owner of a small Vitarium (a business that digs up the dead and gives them the treatment they need before returning them to society), discovers Peak's resurrection is imminent. After accidentally discovering the burial place of Peak, he decides, against the law, to dig up the body before the Anarch awakes. (As with contemporary controversies about brain death, it seems not to be judged morally significant if a heartbeat can be heard, but it is illegal to dig anyone up before they start talking, which suggests resumed brain function is a marker of "old-birth.")
>
> Various groups are interested in controlling the affairs of the 'old-born', such as the Vitaria (technically, a person resurrected is in the legal custody of their Vitarium until claimed by family members) and the Library, an organization dedicated to erasing books which have passed beyond the initial date at which they were written.

Answer (score 3):

This may be Piers Anthony's "Bearing an Hourglass" - the main character lives backwards in time (that is, reverse chronological order), and there is also a section where time started moving backwards for some reason, so buildings get deconstructed, people regurgitate and reassemble their food instead of eating it, and so on.  Time only moves forwards for the main character... but those in his presence become aware of the difference, and can perceive what it was supposed to be - I recall he eats a plate of eggs, while the person next to him had just regurgitated hers, and she becomes aware of the difference in how time is supposed to move and is horrified.

So there is interaction between the directions of time, and things getting done and made and unmade and undone (though I recall the "being uneaten" more than "deconstruction of buildings", could be my memory).  It's also one person seeing time normally, not sections, but as it is a viewpoint character it may be enough.  There are some small differences like that, but it looks like a possible match to me.

Answer (score 3):

This might be Barrington J Bayley's *Collision with Chronos*

> *Collision Course* (1973; vt *Collision with Chronos* 1977)

This difficult to summarize two temporal domains are moving towards each other through time. The civilizations in each of the two temporal sequences sees the evidence of the other civilization in reverse. Ruins gradually becoming more complete and less ruinous.

> The alien ruins that dotted Earth's landscape were an enigma.
>   Archaeologist Rond Heshke dismissed as a ridiculous hoax the photographic evidence which suggested that the ruins disobeyed the laws of time.

Once

> Scientists perfected their time machines that the truth  began to emerge piece by piece: that the builders of the ruins belonged not to the stars but to Earth's future, and that the dreaded confrontation was indeed shortly due

A terrible fate awaited the planet.

> For Earth was to be the victim of an extraordinary cosmic accident. Time itself was about to collide! Mankind's leaders became even more fanatical, pressing on with new plans, determined at all costs to survive ...

Barrington J Bayley was a uniquely inventive science fiction writer, often taking the most bizarre concepts and creating stories with a surreal, dreamlike logic that was rigorous locked into a quasi-scientific framework. Sadly neglected, he deserves to be rediscovered. Reading his short stories and novels was like embarking on a roller coaster ride of the mind.

EDIT:
I found a reasonable summary of Bayley's *Collision Course*.

> COLLISION COURSE has a group of Aryan supremacist archeologists discover an ancient ruin which seems to be getting younger day by day. As the scientists start to wonder about this, a discovery is made that time apparently moves in waves through the galaxy and that their time is on a collision course with another. Both of these societies begin to prepare for a war, while a third, peculiar nation is doing pioneering work in the field of time-manipulation.

This frantic blurb captures the mad hatter's logic of the story well.

> It couldn't be true - but it was.
>
> The ancient ruins that dotted Earth's landscape seemed to be
>   disobeying the laws of time, become less and less decrepit as the
>   years went by.
>
> Everyone had his own theory, but it was only when scientists perfected
>   their time machines that the awful truth dawned. The ruins were
>   getting younger every day, and the builders came not from the past but
>   from Earth's own future, from a society occupying the same planet yet
>   moving in time in the opposite direction, their present lying in the
>   Earth's future, their future in Earth's past.
>
> The two worlds were hurtling towards each other in time at a
>   terrifying speed. Soon, unless something drastic was done, the two
>   would collide and both would be annihilated in a horrific and
>   extraordinary cosmic accident...